# Arguments passed from request library are received but they aren't received when the arguments are sent from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js server and I'm making `GET` requests.
The arguments passed using Python's `requests` and JavaScripts's `request` are received properly.

```
// Python
requests.get(url, data=data)

// JS
request.get({url: url, form:form}, function(){})
```

But the data is not received when I make the request from a browser like: `url?a=1&b=2`.

How do I fix it?

This is the function that I'm using to parse the form data:

```
function extractData(request, response, callback, options) {
  var jsonString = '';
  request.on('data', function(data) {
    jsonString += data;
  });
  request.on('end', function() {
    data = qs.parse(jsonString);
    callback(request, response, data, options);
  });
}
```

`data` is blank when I pass the arguments from URL.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful and below code is working to me

```
var options = {
      host: 'services.com',
      path: '/app/server.js/index/',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length': data.length
      }
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      var msg = '';

      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        msg += chunk;//'chunk' response from server
        if(chunk != "available")
        {
            var mail = {
                from: "abc@gmail.com",
                to: "ddd@gmail.com",
                subject: "Alert! from production server",
                html: "<p>Hi Team,</p> <p>Alert! production server is down.</p><p>Thanks,<br/>Maintenance Team</p>"
            };

            transporter.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    //res.send({ "result" : "failure" });
                }else{
                    console.log("Message sent: " + response);
                    //res.send({ "result" : "success" });
                }
            });
        }
      });
      res.on('end', function() {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
        console.log(msg);
      });
```